# Virtual Directory in Tomcat don't Work

Tags: windows, tomcat, virtual-directory

Tomcat virtual directory does not work.

Hi, I have this problem with Tomcat 7 , it works when the reference is to a local folder, but if it's to a folder on another computer then this is not recognized.

This is the configuration I am using
<
Context path="/POS" docBase="\SERVER1\temp\pdfs" debug="0" privileged="true">

The referenced directory is shared and if I can see it from the browser, has read and write permissions .

Tomcat is running on Windows XP and the other computer is a Windows 2003

This is the error:

dic 09, 2013 11:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
Grave: Error arrancando Recursos estáticos
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: El Documento base \SERVER1\temp\pdfs no existe o no es un directorio legible
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4836)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1247)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:222)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Thanks.

Comment: Is Tomcat running as a service?

Comment: \SERVER1\temp\pdfs is not a valid UNC path. It should be \\SERVER1\temp\pdfs

Comment: Your `/POS` should not be specified in `<Context>`. You should use `POS.war` or `CATALINA_BASE/conf/[Engine][/Host]/POS.xml` and let Tomcat auto-detect the application name.

Comment: Yes, is running as a windows service

Comment: The correct path is \\SERVER1 \temp\pdfs. Copying text is delete the backslash

Answer (score 1):

Try mapping the share to a local drive (say `F:` maps to `\\\SERVER1\temp`) and then specify the drive in docbase. Eg

```
<Context path="/POS" docBase="F:/pdfs" debug="0" privileged="true">
```

Comment: That should work. How are you invoking tomcat ? Are you running it locally or as a Windows service ?

Comment: Is running as a windows service

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I tried it and it worked well:

**Open Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services. Double click on the Tomcat service. Go to the Log On tab. Select "This account", then fill in your credentials.**

http://www.coderanch.com/t/594397/Tomcat/Shared-folder-accessible-running-tomcat

Thanks for the suggestions.